# Mapping column names to random forest feature importances

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to plot feature importances for a random forest model and map each feature importance back to the original coefficient. I've managed to create a plot that shows the importances and uses the original variable names as labels but right now it's ordering the variable names in the order they were in the dataset (and not by order of importance). How do I order them in order of feature importance? Thanks!

[image]

My code is:

```
importances = brf.feature_importances_
std = np.std([tree.feature_importances_ for tree in brf.estimators_],
         axis=0)
indices = np.argsort(importances)[::-1]

# Print the feature ranking
print("Feature ranking:")

for f in range(x_dummies.shape[1]):
    print("%d. feature %d (%f)" % (f + 1, indices[f], importances[indices[f]]))

# Plot the feature importances of the forest
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
plt.title("Feature importances")
plt.bar(range(x_train.shape[1]), importances[indices],
   color="r", yerr=std[indices], align="center")
feature_names = x_dummies.columns
plt.xticks(range(x_dummies.shape[1]), feature_names)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.xlim([-1, x_dummies.shape[1]])
plt.show()
```

Comment: You haven't included the plots you're currently getting?

Comment: Edited! I wasn't sure the plot added much value because I'm just trying to change the order of the x labels on the bottom. Apologies for the tiny font, it was the only way to fit most of the picture into a screenshot.

Comment: `plt.bar(range(x_dummies.shape[1]), importances[indices],
   color="r", yerr=std[indices], align="center")` ?

Comment: You're right that x_train should be x_dummies but unfortunately that doesn't change the plot.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A sort of generic solution would be to throw the features/importances into a dataframe and sort them before plotting:

```
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline
#do code to support model
#"data" is the X dataframe and model is the SKlearn object

feats = {} # a dict to hold feature_name: feature_importance
for feature, importance in zip(data.columns, model.feature_importances_):
    feats[feature] = importance #add the name/value pair 

importances = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(feats, orient='index').rename(columns={0: 'Gini-importance'})
importances.sort_values(by='Gini-importance').plot(kind='bar', rot=45)
```

Answer (score 8):

It is simple, I plotted it like this.

```
feat_importances = pd.Series(extraTree.feature_importances_, index=X.columns)
feat_importances.nlargest(15).plot(kind='barh')
plt.title("Top 15 important features")
plt.show()
```

Comment: I subscribe to this answer.

Answer (score 7):

I use a similar solution to Sam:

```
import pandas as pd
important_features = pd.Series(data=brf.feature_importances_,index=x_dummies.columns)
important_features.sort_values(ascending=False,inplace=True)
```

I always just print the list using `print important_features` but to plot you could always use [`Series.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.html)

Answer (score 3):

Another simple way to get a sorted list

```
importances = list(zip(xgb_classifier.feature_importances_, df.columns))
importances.sort(reverse=True)
```

Next code adds a visualization if it's necessary

```
pd.DataFrame(importances, index=[x for (_,x) in importances]).plot(kind = 'bar')
```